# How to Combine two Rows into One MSSQL

Tags: sql-server

I have an MSSQL table, I want to combine the name from two rows into one. The First Name is the lesser value and the Second Name is of greater value. If the two values are same it just combines the first and second name.

Each line contains 2 names first1 and First2 separated by a space(Salary or First1 less than salary or First2

Currently, the result is:

[image]

I want the result to be like

```
Buchanan Suyama
Peacock Callahan
Dodsworth King
Leverling Davolio
Fuller
```

Comment: Just using simple order by Salary ASC

Comment: What is sql version?

Comment: Peacock Callahan have different salaries... what is your logic? why would they be merged?

Comment: Peacock's wages is less than Callahan's

Comment: i can understand that if they have the same salary, but they have different salaries. What if 10 people have the same salary, you're not going to get the names in the correct order. I don't believe this is the question you should be asking, there has to be an underlying design problem for you to have to do this. Fix the problem instead of trying to work around it.

Answer (score 2):

```
    CREATE TABLE ABC 
(
COLUMN_1 VARCHAR(10),
PRICE INT
)
INSERT INTO ABC VALUES
('A',100),
('B',200),
('C',300),
('D',400),
('E',500),
('F',600),
('G',700),
('H',800),
('I',900)

SELECT Concat(COLUMN_1, ' ', t) AS ADDEDVALUE 
    FROM   (SELECT *,
                   Lead(COLUMN_1, 1)OVER (ORDER BY PRICE) AS t
            FROM   ABC)A 

OUTPUT
ADDEDVALUE
A B
B C
C D
D E
E F
F G
G H
H I
I
```

Answer (score 2):

Chanukaya's answer is great, for older versions use this

```
SELECT Min(title),
       case when Min(title) = Max(title) then '' else Max(title) end
FROM   (SELECT *,
               ( Row_number() OVER( ORDER BY salary) - 1 ) / 2 + 1 as Grp
        FROM   yourtable) a 
Group By Grp
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can,

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Salary) AS RowId,
        LastName ,
        Salary
    FROM 
        Employees   
)

SELECT
    currentRow.LastName + ' ' + nextRow.LastName
FROM 
    CTE currentRow LEFT JOIN 
    CTE nextRow ON currentRow.RowId = nextRow.RowId - 1
WHERE
    currentRow.RowId % 2 <> 0
```